# Tkinter bind not working when passed root.destroy directly

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm fairly new to python and tkinter. I'm working with python 2.7 and tkinter 8.5.

I'm trying to exit my app when the escape key is pressed, and I ran into some odd behaviour:

When I pass root.destoy as the argument to bind(), the app does nothing:

```
root = Tk()
...
root.bind('<Escape>', root.destroy)
```

But if I define a function that calls root.destroy() and pass that as an argument to bind, everything works as expected:

```
def exit_app():
    root.destroy()
root.bind('<Escape>', exit_app)
```

It also works if I pass a lambda like this:

```
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda f: root.destroy())
```

Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Thanks

Comment: I find it really hard to believe that it works with `exit_app`. That should give the exact same error as when you bind directly to root.destroy.

Comment: @furas sorry the typo only exists in this post (I did not copy and paste, it's just a simplified example). Editing the post right now. Thanks

Comment: @BryanOakley Why do you find it hard to believe? It's working on my machine

Comment: do you get error message when you run it in console ? you should - `bind` executes function with one argument and you define `exit_app()` without arguments

Comment: If it's working, please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Posting a "simplified example" isn't good enough, because your simplified example isn't a good representation of your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind a command to an event, that command is passed an argument which is is an object that represents the event. `root.destroy` does not accept any arguments, therefore it is throwing an error instead of running.

That is why  your lambda works: your lambda accepts an argument (oddly, named `f`).

You claim in your question that it works with this exact function definition:

```
def exit_app():
    root.destroy()
```

I find that impossible to believe, for the same reason described above.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. In my real code I called a button handler with signature "def btn_click(*args):" and call root.destroy() inside it. Sorry for the mess, I did not think it was important. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: @AwerMuller: if you had taken the time to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you probably would have learned on your own that the argument was a critical component. That is why we ask for an MCVE -- often, the effort of creating it will expose the problem without you having to ask a question here. At the very least, it would have enabled you to write a better question.